# Symfony 3 Error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) 500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm trying to configure sessions in Symfony 3 (http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html), and I'm getting this error:

```
Error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: )
500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

Stack Trace

in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 113 

110. if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && headers_sent($file, $line)) {
111.     throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "%s" at line %d.', $file, $line));
112. }
113. if (!session_start()) {
114.     throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to start the session');
115. }
116. $this->loadSession();
```

Do you have any ideas, why it;s occurring?

Comment: Have you checked session save_path in to ini file its not commented ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it, it is set to
    session.save_path = /tmp
phpinfo() also confirms it.

Comment: have you checked the PDO connection ? is it connected ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it, I've tried to create tables from script

Comment: Just FYI, I'm using docker php-fpm (all symfony/php configuration I'm doing in this container) + docker mariadb (with using sockets, socket file is also accessible from php-fpm container), maybe it will help to better understand the environment. PHP-FPM - 7.1.0, Mariadb - 10.1.13

Comment: Then might be you need to check your docker's php.ini file to confirm save path.

Comment: I have already checked it, it looks fine, and phpinfo() also confirms it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In my case in docker configuration for my database server I'm using socket, so I just needed to add it to my config.yml file:

```
parameters:
    database_unix_socket: /.../mysqld.sock
```

And then use this config in doctrine.dbal.unix_socket:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        unix_socket: '%database_unix_socket%'
```

Cheers,
Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently with symfony running in docker container. The reason in my case was that PdoSessionHandler couldn't connect to the database. In the official tutorial they show an example without host key in DSN which probably works fine for the most installations. In the end my service definitions looks this way:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
    arguments:
        - 'mysql:dbname=%database_name%;host=%database_host%'
        - { db_username: '%database_user%', db_password: '%database_password%' }
```

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, I will check it this week and let you know.